# Merge the next line if the current line contains a pattern at the end

Tags: awk, sed, tr

I have a very big text file. I want to merge the next line into the current line if the current line has a word OR in the end.
Eg. Like in the lines below

```
somerandomstring OR
someotherrandomstring
```

The above 2 lines should become

```
somerandomstring OR someotherrandomstring
```

Only those lines should change. Rest of the lines must be kept as they are. Thanks in advance.

Allow me to extend the question a bit further.
I want to also see if the next line starts with OR and the OR is not in the end of the current line, then how to achieve the above case and this case together?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/ OR$/{N;s/\n/ /}' file
```

Search white space followed by`OR` at end of line (`$`) and if found then read next line (`N`) to pattern space and replace newline in pattern space (with `s///`) by one white space.

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `awk` by assigning the "OR" row to a variable and printing whatever is stored in the variable when there is no "OR" found.

```
awk '$NF=="OR"{buffer=buffer$0" "} $NF!="OR"{print buffer$0;buffer=""}' test.txt
```

This also works on multiple rows that may have "OR" by concatenating the row to the `buffer` variable until it finds a non-OR row, prints it and clears the `buffer` variable.

---

Another option in `awk` is to use `printf` on the OR rows and `print` on the non-or rows (which is kind of similar to the GNU sed example by @cyrus, but in awk)

```
awk '$NF=="OR"{printf "%s ", $0} $NF!="OR"{print $0}' test.txt
```

And this is the same beast, but using a ternary operator within `printf`:

```
awk '{printf $NF=="OR"?"%s ":"%s\n", $0}' test.txt
```

Comment: Yes it is working. Thanks. Can you please tell if the next line also starts with a OR (not the last line) then how can I achieve the same. I want to consider both the cases together.

Comment: So would that be like:  "Line 1 OR/Line 2/OR Line3" and you would want outputted "Line 1 OR Line 2 OR Line 3"?

Comment: Ahh.. Actually there is no requirement that "Line 1 OR/Line2/OR Line 3" have to be in that order. The occurrence of OR at the end of the line or at the beginning of the line is completely random.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$2$ awk -v RS='^$' -v k='OR' '{gsub(k ORS,k FS); gsub(ORS k,FS k); printf "%s",$0}' file

x OR y
x OR y
```

for test input file

```
$ cat file

x OR
y
x
OR y
```